# Why do I get an unexpected template string expression error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby, eslint

Is it possible to use map array data (`${adv_event.title}`) inside a `react-structured-data` JSX?

I tried adding backticks with no success: `` name: "`${adv_event.title}`", ``

Attempt 1:

```
<Generic jsonldtype="event" schema={{
  name: "${adv_event.title}", 
  description: "",
  startDate: "YYYY-MM-DDT:HH:MM",
  endDate: "YYYY-MM-DDT:HH:MM",
  image: "",
}}>
```

Error:

> 296:31  warning  Unexpected template string expression 
>   no-template-curly-in-string

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an warning generated by ESLint: [no-template-curly-in-string](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-template-curly-in-string)

> Disallow template literal placeholder syntax in regular strings
>   (no-template-curly-in-string)
>
> ECMAScript 6 allows programmers to create strings containing variable
>   or expressions using template literals, instead of string
>   concatenation, by writing expressions like `${variable}` between two
>   backtick quotes (`). It can be easy to use the wrong quotes when
>   wanting to use template literals, by writing `"${variable}"`, and end up
>   with the literal value `"${variable}"` instead of a string containing
>   the value of the injected expressions.

If you want to just assign that variable you should do this:

```
<Generic jsonldtype="event" schema={{
    name: adv_event.title, 
    description: "",
    startDate: "YYYY-MM-DDT:HH:MM",
    endDate: "YYYY-MM-DDT:HH:MM",
    image: "",
}}>
```

A template string is not needed in your case.

Answer (score 12):

Use back quote before and after the expression `` `${adv_event.title}` `` instead of `"${adv_event.title}"`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

I was stuck with similar issue until I realized that the single or double quotes (''/ "") should not be used. The variable should be enclosed between backticks only (``).