# Unexpected template string expression(no-template-curly-in-string)

Tags: reactjs, eslint

this my code

`` const y = "`${x()}${y()}`" ``

I get a warning `Unexpected template string expression(no-template-curly-in-string)`.
how to get rid of the warning ?

Comment: Does your code currently work as you're expecting it to?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do I get an unexpected template string expression error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57874087/why-do-i-get-an-unexpected-template-string-expression-error)

Comment: Valid syntax would be: `const y = `${x()}${y()}``

Comment: @CertainPerformance yes because i created just a line

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the backticks, eg:

```
const y = `\`${x()}${y()}\``;
```